# Element is not clickable inside of a for loop in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor-cucumber frame work with protractor 5.2.2 and mssql 3.3.0.We have a requirement of get db values,i am able to get db data values into my protractor code, But i am not able to click on a element with that db value.My code is given below.

```
function ConnectDB() { 
  var config = {
    user: 'sam',
    password: 'Passw0rd',
    server: 'xxxxxx',
    port: '50866',
    database: 'testDB',
    options: {
     trustedConnection: true
    }
  } 

 sql.connect(config, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err+" db connection failed");     
  var request = new sql.Request();

  request.query('SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE ID = 2', function (err, loc){       
    if (err) console.log(err+" loc_name failed");
      var loc_count= loc.length;        
      console.log(loc_count);
      console.log(loc[0].Location_name);

      var i;    
      for (i=0; i<loc_count; i++){
        if(loc_count!=0 & loc_count%10==0){
         element(by.css(.publish)).click();
        }
        element(by.cssContainingText("span", loc[i].Location_name)).click();
        console.log(loc[i].Location_name);
        browser.sleep(4000);
        element(by.css(.post)).sendKeys("test"); 
        element(by.css(.submit)).click();
      }
   });
 });
}
```

Here the click() and senkeys() functions inside of the for loop is not working.But i am able to console the values of loc_count and loc[i].Location_name.How can i solve this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your issue is that the scripts of loop body almost executed async. All Protractor APIs are async. Thus the `sendKeys` `click()`, `sleep()` inside the loop are executed async. But the loop iterate sync.

This lead to when the `i==loc_count`, the `click()/sendKeys()/sleep()` of the `i==0` have not been executed (They are async).

One solution is to use `Closure` to keep the `i` for each iteration. Another solution is use ES6 `async/await`.

Below is the code example of solution one:

```
  var i;    
  for (i=0; i<loc_count; i++){
    (function(j){
       if(loc_count!=0 && loc_count%10==0){
          element(by.css('.publish')).click();
       }
       element(by.cssContainingText("span", loc[j].Location_name)).click();
       console.log(loc[j].Location_name);
       browser.sleep(4000);
       element(by.css('.post')).sendKeys("test"); 
       element(by.css('.submit')).click();
    })(i)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried above code. But if the wait time is less, it doesn't executing the full length for loop, instead it goes to next feature step after executing the for loop once. But we cannot hard code the wait time, because we don't know the length of the for loop. So how can i give wait until it fully executing the for loop and then only it should goes to the next feature step.

Answer (score 0):

As yong stated it is because your for loop is synchronous and the protractor actions are async. You either need to implement async/await or use the `then` callbacks to make it work correctly.

Async/Await option:

```
request.query('SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE ID = 2', async function (err, loc){       
if (err) console.log(err+" loc_name failed");
  var loc_count= loc.length;        
  console.log(loc_count);
  console.log(loc[0].Location_name);

  var i;    
  for (i=0; i<loc_count; i++){
    if(loc_count!=0 & loc_count%10==0){
     await element(by.css(.publish)).click();
    }
    await element(by.cssContainingText("span", loc[i].Location_name)).click();
    console.log(loc[i].Location_name);
    await browser.sleep(4000);
    await element(by.css(.post)).sendKeys("test"); 
    await element(by.css(.submit)).click();
  }
```

});

To use the `then` callbacks it would be a little more difficult to handle your `if` block correctly but essentially you will need to do something like this to get it to work.

```
element(by.cssContainingText("span", loc[i].Location_name)).click().then(() -> {
    console.log(loc[i].Location_name);
    browser.sleep(4000).then(() => {
        element(by.css(.post)).sendKeys("test").then(() => {
              element(by.css(.submit)).click();
        });
    });
});
```

The first option is far easier to read and implement correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :-

var elm = element(by.id("myid"));

browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement());